# Creating a JAR using Ant but not including external jars inside

Tags: java, ant

I've recently come with the need to create for a Java project a build.xml file in which is meant to be run using the terminal.

The issue is that until now we've used Eclipse as the utility to run the build.xml while depending on Eclipse UI to let the Ant package manager to create our jars, but not putting the external jars in each jar we create.

That way, the memory in which the jar libraries take(~40MB) isn't replicated to each Jar we make.

I'm pretty a beginner in Ant so what I'm trying to do is create a build.xml in which take a folder of Jar libraries, and for the project which is a Jar library itself, create the Jar while knowing the libraries but not include them in the end Jar.

I alternatively tried understanding how eclipse teels the build.xml for ant but the classpath of the project, how to access the jars and other configurations, so if there's a possibility for that then it will be much better.

If possible, it would be great to help with that.
I've tried of course seeing other questions on Stackoverflow but didn't saw something similar to this.
If there's one of course I'll be happy to see it :)
Thanks heads up! :)

Comment: *"I'm pretty a beginner in Ant"* Then you should start by reading the documentation.

Comment: That's straightforward: it's either a fat jar (you ruled that out) or including the necessary jars in a (class)path element for the java task